# SQL - Group values with an alias

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a simple query as follows which returns all items from products;

```
SELECT Item
FROM Products
```

Is there a way I can group the values and have an alias for each group of values?

*For example;*

Above query will return similar to the following;

```
cauliflower
celery
endive
fiddleheads
frisee
fennel
greens
Lamb
Beef
Chicken
```

**Desired results:**

Group 1 called vegetables containing;

```
    cauliflower
    celery
    endive
    fiddleheads
    frisee
    fennel
    greens
```

Group 2 called Meat containing;

```
    Lamb
    Beef
    Chicken
```

In my select statement if I could do the following;

```
SELECT Meat, Vegetables
FROM Products
```

Which will then return;

```
cauliflower
celery
endive
fiddleheads
frisee
fennel
greens
Lamb
Beef
Chicken
```

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: We need to see data to answer this, I think.  Ideally, you would already have a column in your table called `category`, or something like that.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: @TiMBiegeleisen, Yes there is a table called ItemType but does not contain types as requested above.  I am trying to avoid adding additional types that will differ from current types in this table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create groups with SQL, however the language itself cannot determine whether Lamb is meat or vegetable based on the string value of 'Lamb'. You will manually have to create the groups in a query, or add a new column with the value for easy use in your system

Comment: I thought this would be the case too but thought I'd chance it to see if there is another way to do it.  There is over 800+ products so yes, that would be very manual.

Comment: What use cases does the groups have?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need simple `where` clause :

```
SELECT Item, <do aggregation whatever you need (i.e. count(), sum(), min/max)> 
FROM Products
WHERE Item = 'meat'
GROUP BY Item;
```

You can use `case` expression to define the groups for instance i would do :

```
SELECT (case when Item in ('lamb', 'beef', 'chicken') then 'meat' else 'other' end) as Item, 
       <do aggregation whatever you need (i.e. count(), sum(), min/max)> 
FROM Products
GROUP BY (case when Item in ('lamb', 'beef', 'chicken') then 'meat' else 'other' end);
```

Comment: There is not item called 'meat' so the WHERE clause will not work.  I have items such as lamb, beef or chicken which i would like to be part of a group called 'Meat'.